# Getting Relative Values in Each Loop jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, foreach

I'm having an issue pulling the relative values in .each() loop in jQuery. I have a series of table rows that have an text input and a radio button next to them. I want to loop through each row, and if the radio button is selected, save the value for the text input.

However, so far whenever I run my loop, it seems to recognize that one of the radio values is selected, and then it automatically saves the first input, regardless of which row. I thought that by running through each row, the code would only be executed in that particular rows HTML -- I believe it's touching all the rows instead. Can anyone help?

Here's my jQuery:

```
$('#valueTable tbody tr').each( function() {
   //$(this).css('background', 'blue');

   if($('td input[name=DefaultVal]:checked').size() > 0){
       $('td input[name=DefaultVal]:checked').parent().css('background', 'red')
       selectedDefVal = $('td:first-child input[name=valueTextField]').val();
       //alert(selectedDefVal)
   }  else {
      alert('not checked')
   }
  });
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<table border="0" id="valueTable">        
<tr>
     <td width="70%" style="white-space: nowrap;"><input size="80" type="text" name="valueTextField" placeholder="Enter Value" value="" ></td>        
     <td width="70%" class="default_container">Default
        <input type="radio" name="DefaultVal" checked="true" class="defaultValFind" />  
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td width="70%" style="white-space: nowrap;"><input size="80" type="text" name="valueTextField" placeholder="Enter Value" value="2" ></td>        
     <td width="70%" class="default_container">Default
       <input type="radio" name="DefaultVal" class="defaultValFind" /> 
     </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
     <td width="70%" style="white-space: nowrap;"><input size="80" type="text" name="valueTextField" placeholder="Enter Value" value="fffffff" ></td>        
     <td width="70%" class="default_container">Default
       <input type="radio" name="DefaultVal" class="defaultValFind" /> 
     </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use something like $(this):

```
$('#valueTable tbody tr').each(function() {
   if($(this).find('td input[name=DefaultVal]:checked').length){
       $(this).find('td input[name=DefaultVal]:checked').parent().css('background', 'red');
       selectedDefVal = $(this).find('td:first-child input[name=valueTextField]').val();
   }  else {
      alert('not checked')
   }
});
```

Comment: This is great (and works perfectly)! Do you always need to use $(this) to make the selectors relevant to what you looping through? I guess my other selectors were getting the global list?

Comment: `size()` should be replaced with `length`, and you don't have to check for zero values, as that would be false anyway. An easier solution would probably be something like [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/3gyrH/), +1 anyway, as it works.

Comment: Using $(this) is the best way in my opinion.  You can also set index and element on the each function .each(function(index, Element)) and then use those variables how you want.

Comment: @streetlight Yes, `$(this)` is the result of the `each()` method, so using it as above will make the `td` selector relevant to the selected `tr`

Comment: @adeneo , why is .length better than .size()? Is it faster?

Comment: It actually, probably, maybe, is a little faster. `length` is not a function, it's a property, while `size()` is a jQuery function that does the exact same thing as `length`. Look at the documentation on jQuery's website for `size()`, and it will say right at the top that `length` should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#valueTable tbody tr').each( function() {
   //$(this).css('background', 'blue');

   if($('td input[name=DefaultVal]:checked', this).size() > 0){
       $('td input[name=DefaultVal]:checked', this).parent().css('background', 'red')
       selectedDefVal = $('td:first-child input[name=valueTextField]', this).val();
       //alert(selectedDefVal)
   }  else {
      alert('not checked')
   }
  });
```

I thinks when using $ to select children elments, you forget to specify the parent scope. if omitted, it will be window by default. In this .each case, this will point to the tr element in every loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help! How is this solution better than using $(this)?

Comment: the grammar is clean I think. ;-) Internally $(selector, scope) still calls fn.find(). And by the way, I'm afraid $(this) may have tiny performance hit, and if you use $(selector, scope), jquery may use some shortcut way to find the children elements.